# Is a 12V voltage step-up USB to 4-Pin PC adapter safe to use in an enclosed space for extended periods of time?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, safety, overheat

I am interested in using an adapter cable such as this to power a 4-Pin fan through usb:

[image]

The fan specifications are as follows:

[image]

Now, my question is this - Is something like this safe to use for an extended period of time in a mostly enclosed space? I am concerned that it will get hot, maybe overheat, and be dangerous. Assume the build quality of the converter is adequate. I had never heard of one of these until now and just wanted to be safe before making the purchase. Thank you in advance!

**P.S. - I know *nothing* about electrical things so sorry if this is a dumb question or if you need more details to answer. Thanks.**

Comment: The fan is one I already picked out - I got the info from their website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this one would be fine.  Like any new purchase, don't trust it alone until you've babysat it a little while, but assuming it's not defective you should be safe...you're not even getting close to capacity with the 53mA your fan is using.  It's designed for 400mA.